# How does Haskell hide data constructor?

Tags: haskell, constructor, system

I explored System.Random.StdGen and saw this code in the source.

```
data StdGen = StdGen Int32 Int32
```

It seems the module export StdGen too.

```
module System.Random (

    RandomGen(next, split, genRange)

    , StdGen

    ...
```

However, why can't I do this in my code, say like,

```
Prelude System.Random> StdGen 1 2

Not in scope: data constructor `System.Random.StdGen'**
```

In the other hand, I can do this,

```
module F (Foo) where

    import GHC.Int

    data Foo = Foo GHC.Int.Int32 GHC.Int.Int32 deriving (Show)
```

and

```
Prelude> Foo 1 2

Foo 1 2
```

Would someone please kindly tell me how actually this data constructor is hidden?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two things to understand here. Export syntax and a difference in GHCi behaviour between compiled and interpreted values.

#### Export syntax

Exporting from a module using this syntax

```
module System.Random (
    -- ...
    , StdGen
    -- ...
```

tells GHC only to export the datatype, not the constructor (even if both have the same name). The constructor can be listed explicitly within parentheses after the datatype name if you want to export it, like this:

```
    StdGen(StdGen)
```

Or you can export a datatype with all its constructors like this:

```
    StdGen(..)
```

#### GHCi behaviour

In addition, GHCi, when loading an *interpreted* module, always allows you to see all the entities visisble at the top-level of the module, even if they're hidden by the export list. This is to facilitate development and debugging, and is the reason why your `Foo` is visible.

This mode where "everything" is visible is reflected by putting a `*` in front of the module name at the GHCi prompt. If there's a `*`, everything is visisble, and if not, then the exported entities are visible.

When using the `:m` command to add or remove modules from scope, you can select whether you want to add modules in `*`-form or not.

*But* for *compiled* modules (and a library module like `System.Random` usually is compiled), the `*`-form is not available, so for these you'll always be in the situation that the export list is respected.

See [the documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-scope) for a full description of the scoping behaviour of GHCi.

Comment: So it has to do with GHCi. Thank you a lot!!

Comment: It should be mentioned that it's only for modules loaded in `*` form that ghci disregards the export list.

Comment: @DanielFischer Aren't the interpreted modules in `*` form and the compiled modules are not?

Comment: If modules imported from the top-level module are interpreted, they're not loaded in `*` form (at least by default).

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, if they're indirectly imported, then they're not in scope at all, which is yet again different. Anyway, I've tried to clarify my answer, and provide a link to the actual documentation of the behaviour.

Comment: Yes. I may accidentally set one flag wrong. It is *F> instead of F>

Comment: And here are active language flags:
  -XPatternGuards
  -XEmptyDataDecls
  -XForeignFunctionInterface
  -XImplicitPrelude
  -XMonomorphismRestriction
  -XDoAndIfThenElse
  -XNondecreasingIndentation
  -XTraditionalRecordSyntax
  -XRelaxedPolyRec

Comment: Well, their exports are in scope (at least what is imported from them). And if you `:m +Foo`, the export list is respected, but with `:m +*Foo`, you get all. Anyway, issue addressed.

Comment: I imported by :m +Foo but get *F>

Comment: @DanielFischer I think I created confusion because I was implicitly mixing up loading with `:l` and switching scope with `:m` or `import`. Loading uses `*`-form by default, but `:m` does not. I've tried to clarify my answer yet again.

Answer (score 8):

If you [look at the sources](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/1.0.1.1/doc/html/src/System-Random.html#RandomGen), you'll see something along the lines of:

```
module System.Random
    (
    -- stuff...
    , StdGen
    -- even more stuff...
    )
```

This syntax means that only the *type* is exported, not its constructor(s). If you want to export the constructor too, you'd do:

```
module System.Random
    ( StdGen(..)
    -- ...
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! ...but I have tried this in my Foo, why can I still see my data constructor Foo?